# Update an nvarchar column with a new json value, without adding quotes to the new value

Tags: sql-server, json, varchar

I've got the following table, where `[Data]` is of type `nvarchar(max)` and its values are valid json strings:

| Id | Data |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `{ "info" : { "done": true, "chosenOptions": ["one", "two"] } }` |
| `2` | `{ "info" : { "done": true, "chosenOptions": ["one"] } }` |
| `3` | `{ "info" : { "done": true, "chosenOptions": [] } }` |
| `4` | `{ "info" : { "done": true } }` |

I want to update all rows whose `Data` doesn't include `chosenOptions`, or where `chosenOptions` is `[]`.

- Assume that each `Data` json value has several other properties than those shown here, if that matters.

My query:

```
declare @defaultValue Nvarchar(100);
set @defaultValue = JSON_QUERY('["one", "two"]')    

update myTable
set [Data] = JSON_QUERY(JSON_MODIFY([Data], '$.info.chosenOptions', @defaultValue))
where JSON_QUERY([data], '$.info.chosenOptions') IS NULL or 
      JSON_QUERY([data], '$.info.chosenOptions') = '[]'
```

The resultant `chosenOptions` value is a string instead of an array (please ignore the escaping of the array values, this is less important here):

| Id | Data |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `{ "info" : { "done": true, "chosenOptions": ["one", "two"] } }` |
| `2` | `{ "info" : { "done": true, "chosenOptions": ["one"] } }` |
| `3` | `{ "info" : { "done": true, "chosenOptions": "[\"one\", \"two\"]" } }` <-- note that it's a string, not array |
| `4` | `{ "info" : { "done": true, "chosenOptions": "[\"one\", \"two\"]" } }` <-- note that it's a string, not array |

I assume that it's an expected behavior, but how can this array be updated properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON_QUERY` with no path is used to prevent escaping of valid JSON strings. **You need to place this directly within the `JSON_MODIFY` call for it to work properly,** you cannot place it outside of the function parameter.

This is pointed out [in the documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> `JSON_MODIFY` escapes all special characters in the new value if the type of the value is `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR`. A text value is not escaped if it is properly formatted JSON produced by `FOR JSON`, `JSON_QUERY`, or `JSON_MODIFY`.

You can also save on re-querying the JSON twice in the `WHERE`, by placing it in `CROSS APPLY`. Don't be tempted to try this for the `JSON_MODIFY` parameter, it doesn't work as I have mentioned

```
declare @defaultValue nvarchar(100) = '["one", "two"]';

update t
set [Data] =
  JSON_MODIFY([Data], '$.info.chosenOptions', JSON_QUERY(@defaultValue))
from myTable t
cross apply (values(
  JSON_QUERY([Data], '$.info.chosenOptions')
)) v(array)
where v.array IS NULL or v.array = '[]';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce49f/7)